# Robocopy script to load balance over 2 destinations

Tags: robocopy

Is it possible to use robocopy in a script/batch to move files to 2 different destinations using same source?  Maybe setup a timer and move 5 files to one destination, then 5 files to the next destination, then loop?

Anybody have an example of such a method?

Like MultiRobo with a load balancing feature.  Move 5 files to destination 1(D1), then move the next 5 to destination 2(D2), then 5 more to D1, 5 more to D2, until done.